# For using plugin, how to find a list and example code

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had a problem to load models and then collide themselves since miss loading of physics plugin.
https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27844/imported-models-couldnt-collide-each-other/

I have searched this URL ; https://ignitionrobotics.org/libs/plugin, but it is still hard to understand its structure.

In my searching skill, It was hard to find plugin list and examples for me. It would be appreciated if you give me some hints.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/27858/for-using-plugin,-how-to-find-a-list-and-example-code/) by [fonawork](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74720/fonawork/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This [wiki](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/wiki) was to me very interesting.
But is rather difficult to find... :)

I hope it helps you

---

Originally posted by [Nobel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/72088/nobel/) with karma: 26 on 2022-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fonawork](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74720/fonawork/) on 2022-02-23**:
Thank you! have a nice day.

**Comment by [fonawork](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74720/fonawork/) on 2022-02-23**:
Ignition Gazebo with this wiki looks tags are not the same.